# Changing a div's output based off of another div's price

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with some billing info. I want to affect a div based on the values of other divs. But, there is no output in my desired div.

Below is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content-wrapper.planwrapper").each(function() {
        var originalRate = $(this).find(".v-ratePlanValue").text().replace("¢","");
        var newBill = eval(originalRate*500+5.95);
    });
    $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").replace($(this),'$newBill');
});
```

I'm pretty new to JS, so any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is the HTML for one of the divs I'm working with -

```
<div class="esco_electric">
    <div class="esco_lower-wrapper">
        <div class="esco_rates-list" id="electric_list">
            <div class="rate-item row-id-Electric-' . $oneplan->ProductId . '-' . $oneplan->UtilityID . ' color3" data-product-id="' . $oneplan->ProductId . '" data-utility-id="' . $oneplan->UtilityID . '" data-tpv-id="' . $oneplan->TPVTemplateID . '" data-utility-name="' . $oneplan->UtilityShortName . '" data-zone="">
                <!-- Price / Suffix / Plan Type -->

                <div class="rate-type rate-wrapper">
                    <div class="rate-price" style="position:relative;">
                        <div class="mobleft" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Fixed Rate</div>
                        <div id="pricediv-Electric-1853-50" class="price v-ratePlanValue mobcenter" style="padding-top:5px;">7.4<span style="font-size:0.7em;">¢</span></div>
                        <div class="price-suffix v-rateMeasurementSuffix mobright">kWh </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Description Area -->
                <div class="rate-description description-wrapper">
                    <!-- Upper Description -->
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <div class="term-title">Term</div>
                        <div class="term-description">
                            6 Months </div>
                        <div class="description-contentpricediv-Electric-1853-50 v-ratePlanDescription">No Cancellation Fee </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rate-description estimatedbill-wrapper">
                    <div class="description-text">
                        <div class="estimatedbill-title">Estimated Bill</div>
                        <div class="term-description">
                            $148 </div>
                        <div class="v-ratePlanDescription howisthiscalculated" data-mfp-src="#howisthiscalculated-popover">
                            How is this calculated?
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <style>
                    .description-contentpricediv-Electric-1853-50 {
                        margin-top: 19px;
                        text-align: center;
                        font-size: 16px !important;
                        color: #535353!important;
                    }
                </style>

                <!-- Action buttons -->

                <a id="selectrateid-Electric-1853-50" href="index.php?type=resi&amp;s=options_and_information&amp;plan=1853&amp;StartDate=12-May-2016">
                    <div class="selectplan">
                        <p>Select Plan</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="rate-edit" href="#">
                    <img src="images/check.png">
                    <p>
                        Edit&nbsp;Plan
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- end rateitem -->

            <div id="UDSDIVID-Electric-1853-50" data-alert="" class="alert-box radius infodiv">
                <div class="pdfdiv">
                    <a eslinktext="Datos de la Electricidad" eslinkurl="PDFTemplates/ResidentialContracts/EFLViewer.php?lang=es&amp;key=RW5lcmd5Q2hhcmdlPTQuMSZQbGFuTmFtZT1UaGluayBTZWN1cmUgNiZJc3N1ZURhdGU9MDUvMTIvMjAxNiZVdGlsaXR5U2hvcnROYW1lPU9OQ09SJnByb2R1Y3R0ZXJtPTYmdGVybWZlZT0w" class="pdfcustom" href="PDFTemplates/ResidentialContracts/EFLViewer.php?key=RW5lcmd5Q2hhcmdlPTQuMSZQbGFuTmFtZT1UaGluayBTZWN1cmUgNiZJc3N1ZURhdGU9MDUvMTIvMjAxNiZVdGlsaXR5U2hvcnROYW1lPU9OQ09SJnByb2R1Y3R0ZXJtPTYmdGVybWZlZT0w" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;"><img src="images/pdf.png" height="25" width="25"> Electricity Facts Label</a><br>
                    <a eslinktext="Terminos y Condiciones" eslinkurl="PDFTemplates/TermsofServices/TOS_TX_Spanish.pdf?key=c3RhdGU9VFgmcmF0ZT00LjEmdGVybT02JnBsYW5uYW1lPVRoaW5rIFNlY3VyZSA2" class="pdfcustom" href="PDFTemplates/contract_api/index.php/contract/TC/state/TX/customer_type/RESI/service/Electric?PlanName=Think+Secure+6&amp;ContractNumber=TBD&amp;ServiceAddress=&amp;Price=4.1&amp;ServiceCity=&amp;ServiceAddress2=&amp;ServiceState=&amp;ServiceZipCode=&amp;Term=6&amp;MonthEnding=November&amp;Timestamp=1463061182 " target="_blank" style="color:#000000;"><img src="images/pdf.png" height="25" width="25"> Terms of Service</a><br>
                    <a eslinktext="Sus Derechos como Cliente" eslinkurl="PDFTemplates/Contracts/TX_YRAC_Spanish.pdf" class="pdfcustom" href="PDFTemplates/Contracts/TX_YRAC.pdf" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;"><img src="images/pdf.png" height="25" width="25"> Your Rights as a Customer</a><br><br>
                </div>
                <!-- end pdfdiv-->
                <div class="textrightdiv">Please contact Customer Care to request that a written copy of the terms of service document be sent to you by regular U.S. mail.<br><br><span style="padding-right: 30px;">Email Request: </span><a href="mailto:customercare@mythinkenergy.com">customercare@mythinkenergy.com</a><br><span style="padding-right: 25px;">Phone Request: </span>1-888-238-5610<br><a class="small button spanishButton" name="btnshowspanish" id="btnshowspanish22422" onclick="showspanishcontracts('btnshowspanish22422');">Documentos en Español</a></div><a onclick="$('#UDSDIVID-Electric-1853-50').hide();" style="display: none; padding: 10px;color:#000000;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;position: absolute;top: 10px; right: 10px;">X</a>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need the HTML too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct, while your code is incorrect, there are several mistakes that needs to be fixed:

- There's no need to use `eval`, it has no effect in your code and it's better to avoid its use.
- To use the variable `newBill` you don't need to write `$newBill` and
  if you put it inside `''` it will be interpreted as `string` and simply print`the sentence`$newBill`.
- And in your case you declared the variable `newBill` inside `.each` function so it will be `undefined` outside this function scope so you can't use it outside of it, you need to declare it outside it.
- And the use of `$(".content-wrapper.planwrapper").each(function() {` is unnecessary in your case and will break your code.
- And You are using `.replace()` in the wrong place, to change the
  content of a div use `.text(content)` and not `.replace()`.

This is how should be your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newBill = 0;
    var originalRate = $(this).find(".v-ratePlanValue").text().replace("¢", "");
    newBill = parseFloat(originalRate) * 500 + 5.95;
  $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").text(newBill);
});
```

**THis is a working DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newBill = 0;
  var originalRate = $(this).find(".v-ratePlanValue").text().replace("¢", "");
  newBill = parseFloat(originalRate) * 500 + 5.95;
  $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").text(newBill);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="esco_electric
                   ">
  <div class="esco_lower-wrapper">
    <div class="esco_rates-list" id="electric_list">
      <div class="rate-item row-id-Electric-' . $oneplan->ProductId . '-' . $oneplan->UtilityID . ' color3" data-product-id="' . $oneplan->ProductId . '" data-utility-id="' . $oneplan->UtilityID . '" data-tpv-id="' . $oneplan->TPVTemplateID . '" data-utility-name="' . $oneplan->UtilityShortName . '"
      data-zone="">
        <!-- Price / Suffix / Plan Type -->

        <div class="rate-type rate-wrapper">
          <div class="rate-price" style="position:relative;">

            <div class="mobleft" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Fixed Rate</div>


            <div id="pricediv-Electric-1853-50" class="price v-ratePlanValue mobcenter" style="padding-top:5px;">7.4<span style="font-size:0.7em;">¢</span>
            </div>



            <div class="price-suffix v-rateMeasurementSuffix mobright">
              kWh</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Description Area -->
        <div class="rate-description description-wrapper">
          <!-- Upper Description -->
          <div class="description-text">
            <div class="term-title">Term</div>
            <div class="term-description">
              6 Months</div>
            <div class="description-contentpricediv-Electric-1853-50 v-ratePlanDescription">

              No Cancellation Fee</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rate-description estimatedbill-wrapper">
          <div class="description-text">
            <div class="estimatedbill-title">Estimated Bill</div>
            <div class="term-description">
              $148</div>
            <div class="v-ratePlanDescription howisthiscalculated" data-mfp-src="#howisthiscalculated-popover">
              How is this calculated?
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <style>
          .description-contentpricediv-Electric-1853-50 {
            margin-top: 19px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px !important;
            color: #535353!important;
          }
        </style>

        <!-- Action buttons -->

        <a id="selectrateid-Electric-1853-50" href="index.php?type=resi&amp;s=options_and_information&amp;plan=1853&amp;StartDate=12-May-2016">
          <div class="selectplan">
            <p>Select Plan</p>
          </div>
        </a>


        <a class="rate-edit" href="#">
          <img src="images/check.png">
          <p>
            Edit&nbsp;Plan
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- end rateitem -->

      <div id="UDSDIVID-Electric-1853-50" data-alert="" class="alert-box radius infodiv">
        <div class="pdfdiv">
          <a eslinktext="Datos de la Electricidad" eslinkurl="PDFTemplates/ResidentialContracts/EFLViewer.php?lang=es&amp;key=RW5lcmd5Q2hhcmdlPTQuMSZQbGFuTmFtZT1UaGluayBTZWN1cmUgNiZJc3N1ZURhdGU9MDUvMTIvMjAxNiZVdGlsaXR5U2hvcnROYW1lPU9OQ09SJnByb2R1Y3R0ZXJtPTYmdGVybWZlZT0w"
          class="pdfcustom" href="PDFTemplates/ResidentialContracts/EFLViewer.php?key=RW5lcmd5Q2hhcmdlPTQuMSZQbGFuTmFtZT1UaGluayBTZWN1cmUgNiZJc3N1ZURhdGU9MDUvMTIvMjAxNiZVdGlsaXR5U2hvcnROYW1lPU9OQ09SJnByb2R1Y3R0ZXJtPTYmdGVybWZlZT0w" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;">
            <img src="images/pdf.png" height="25" width="25">Electricity Facts Label</a>
          <br>
          <a eslinktext="Terminos y Condiciones" eslinkurl="PDFTemplates/TermsofServices/TOS_TX_Spanish.pdf?key=c3RhdGU9VFgmcmF0ZT00LjEmdGVybT02JnBsYW5uYW1lPVRoaW5rIFNlY3VyZSA2" class="pdfcustom" href="PDFTemplates/contract_api/index.php/contract/TC/state/TX/customer_type/RESI/service/Electric?PlanName=Think+Secure+6&amp;ContractNumber=TBD&amp;ServiceAddress=&amp;Price=4.1&amp;ServiceCity=&amp;ServiceAddress2=&amp;ServiceState=&amp;ServiceZipCode=&amp;Term=6&amp;MonthEnding=November&amp;Timestamp=1463061182 "
          target="_blank" style="color:#000000;">
            <img src="images/pdf.png" height="25" width="25">Terms of Service</a>
          <br>
          <a eslinktext="Sus Derechos como Cliente" eslinkurl="PDFTemplates/Contracts/TX_YRAC_Spanish.pdf" class="pdfcustom" href="PDFTemplates/Contracts/TX_YRAC.pdf" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;">
            <img src="images/pdf.png" height="25" width="25">Your Rights as a Customer</a>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
        <!-- end pdfdiv-->
        <div class="textrightdiv">Please contact Customer Care to request that a written copy of the terms of service document be sent to you by regular U.S. mail.
          <br>
          <br><span style="padding-right: 30px;">Email Request: </span><a href="mailto:customercare@mythinkenergy.com">customercare@mythinkenergy.com</a>
          <br><span style="padding-right: 25px;">Phone Request: </span>1-888-238-5610
          <br><a class="small button spanishButton" name="btnshowspanish" id="btnshowspanish22422" onclick="showspanishcontracts('btnshowspanish22422');">Documentos en Español</a>
        </div><a onclick="$('#UDSDIVID-Electric-1853-50').hide();" style="display: none; padding: 10px;color:#000000;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;position: absolute;top: 10px; right: 10px;">X</a>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it! Man, you guys are amazing with all your help! Thanks so much!

Comment: @JBEverett Great, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/vmtzqnu0/5/

## There are a few things to fix to get this working:

#### 1. Your use of `var`

This keyword creates a variable within the code block (scope) that you use it, but outside of that block it's no longer usable. So when you say `var newBill = ...` inside the `$.each()` loop, you can't use it outside of there.

We can fix this by removing the keyword and (optionally) add the `var newBill;` statement just outside that block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newBill; // will be used later
    $(".content-wrapper.planwrapper").each(function() {
        var originalRate = $(this).find(".v-ratePlanValue").text().replace("¢","");
        newBill = eval(originalRate*500+5.95);
    });
    $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").replace($(this),'$newBill');
});
```

#### 2. Your use of `eval()`

[You should probably just never use `eval()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) Moreover, it doesn't do what you think. You pass it a string of JS code and it will run that code. **You don't pass it a statement.**

So `newBill = eval(originalRate*500+5.95);` becomes `newBill = originalRate*500+5.95;`. You're best off wrapping that in `parseFloat()` too:

```
newBill = parseFloat(originalRate) * 500 + 5.95;
```

#### 3. Your use of `$.replace()`

Here you actually want to use `$.text()` or `$.html()`. These functions are used to replace the content of an element. So, your final code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newBill;

    $(".content-wrapper.planwrapper").each(function() {
        var originalRate = $(this).find(".v-ratePlanValue").text().replace("¢", "");
        newBill = parseFloat(originalRate) * 500 + 5.95;
    });

    $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").text(newBill)
});
```

#### 4. There is no `.planwrapper`

Instead, loop through `.v-ratePlanValue`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newBill;

    $(".v-ratePlanValue").each(function() {
        var originalRate = $(this).text().replace("¢", "");
        console.log(this, originalRate);
        newBill = '$' + ((parseFloat(originalRate) * 500) + 5.95);
    });
    $(this).find(".estimatedbill-wrapper .term-description").text(newBill)
});
```

## Good resources while learning Javascript, jQuery:

- [MDN JS Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)
- [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/)
- [JS Debugging Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful! However, when I checked the jsfiddle and ran it, the estimated bill didn't change. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I'm seeing $148 in the estimated bill portion. What are you seeing?

Comment: I'm seeing $148, as well. It should turn out to be 3705.95 (I know, it's outrageous, but I want to show something unreasonable so I can see the change).

Comment: Sorry about that! It's updated. There was no `.planwrapper` found so now it loops through all `$(".v-ratePlanValue")` instead

Comment: If you don't have multitple `.v-planRateValue` elements on the page, you don't need to loop through them.

Comment: @Martin Well pointed out, that's what I mentioned in my answer in fact I missed it in the first place, but in it's unecessary here.

Comment: Yeah I left the loop in my answer because I'm not sure if this is exactly how it will render  in production.